# Bootstrap 3 - How to get tab bar in navigation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I get a Bootstrap tabbar into the header top bar? (see screenshot)[image: Tabbar in header top bar]

This is my code at this moment:

```
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
           <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="navbar-header">
                 <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                 <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                 </button>
                 <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">AppName</a>
              </div>
              <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                 <form method="post" id="logoutForm" class="navbar-right" action="/Account/LogOff">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="margin-right: 20px">
                       <li>
                          <a title="Manage" href="/Account/Claims">User</a>
                       </li>
                       <li>
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link navbar-btn navbar-link">Log off</button>
                       </li>
                    </ul>
                 </form>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>

        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
           <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
           <li class="active"><a href="#">Link A</a></li>
           <li class=""><a href="#">Link B</a></li>
           <li class=""><a href="#">Link C</a></li>
           <li class=""><a href="#">Link D</a></li>
           <li class=""><a href="/Admin">Admin</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please let me know if the answer below works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to move this code below inside of the navbar-header div after the navbar-brand tag.

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
   <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
   <li class="active"><a href="#">Link A</a></li>
   <li class=""><a href="#">Link B</a></li>
   <li class=""><a href="#">Link C</a></li>
   <li class=""><a href="#">Link D</a></li>
   <li class=""><a href="/Admin">Admin</a></li>
</ul>
```

Your code should look like this

```html
       <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
           <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="navbar-header">
                 <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                 <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                 </button>
                 <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">AppName</a>
                 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                   <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                   <li class="active"><a href="#">Link A</a></li>
                   <li class=""><a href="#">Link B</a></li>
                   <li class=""><a href="#">Link C</a></li>
                   <li class=""><a href="#">Link D</a></li>
                   <li class=""><a href="/Admin">Admin</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                 <form method="post" id="logoutForm" class="navbar-right" action="/Account/LogOff">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="margin-right: 20px">
                       <li>
                          <a title="Manage" href="/Account/Claims">User</a>
                       </li>
                       <li>
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link navbar-btn navbar-link">Log off</button>
                       </li>
                    </ul>
                 </form>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
```